# Django (mod_wsgi) Exception occurred processing WSGI script

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am a beginner at Apache and mod_wsgi. I understand the basic idea of an Apache server though. I need a life savior because I have virtually no one to ask for help.

My problem is as follows:

1. I can run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and my application runs fine on the server
2. However, when I use Apache server to serve my site. Things doesn't work out well.

The two main errors returned are:

```
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

and

```
  ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django_openid.consumer: "cannot import name utils"
```

**Folder Structure**

```
payupjack
  |-payupjack-env (virtualenv for payupjack)
      |- (virtualenv stuffs...)
      |- PayupJack (My application)
           |- All the code required by this application
```

**What I have tried**

1. Changing the user ownership to 'www-data' for the folder django_openid in the virtualenv's site-package folder
2. Added 'www-data' user to the 'ubuntu' group (so that 'www-data' share same privilege as 'ubuntu')
3. Running 'wsgi.py' alone, which runs fine.
4. Running `python manage.py runserver` which is fine too
5. Trying to comment out the line which imports `utils` in the module `consumer.py` (in the django_openid module), but I still get same error. This is really weird and I don't know how to comprehend it.
6. Followed many Stackoverflow suggestions on different variant of this problem. Nothing is working so far.

**Extra info**

The full Apache error log returns the following.

```
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.411960 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632] mod_wsgi (pid=20821): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.411987 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412002 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412091 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412105 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412209 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     mod = import_module(mw_module)
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412224 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412262 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     __import__(name)
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412272 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_openid/consumer.py", line 14, in <module>
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412390 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412403 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412467 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     from django.db.models.manager import Manager
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412477 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412525 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412535 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412595 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412615 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412630 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     return import_module('.base', backend_name)
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412640 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412652 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     __import__(name)
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412659 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 24, in <module>
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412726 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
[Tue Nov 10 20:02:12.412743 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:12632] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.107340 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] mod_wsgi (pid=20821): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.107383 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.107402 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.107426 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.107436 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.107449 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.107467 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django_openid.consumer: "cannot import name utils"
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.407277 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] mod_wsgi (pid=20821): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.407306 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.407322 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.407343 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.407352 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.407364 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:13.407381 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django_openid.consumer: "cannot import name utils"
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.197060 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] mod_wsgi (pid=20821): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.197098 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.197114 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.197136 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.197144 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.197157 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.197174 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django_openid.consumer: "cannot import name utils"
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.252928 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] mod_wsgi (pid=20821): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.252946 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.252958 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.252975 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.252983 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]   File "/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.252994 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Tue Nov 10 15:02:14.253006 2015] [:error] [pid 20821:tid 139665119233792] [remote 192.0.163.234:7512] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django_openid.consumer: "cannot import name utils"
```

The `wsgi.py` is given as:

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler


import os

import sys

import site

ALLDIRS = ['/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack']

# redirect sys.stdout to sys.stderr for bad libraries like geopy that uses

# print statements for optional import exceptions.

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)

print prev_sys_path

site.addsitedir('/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

sys.path.append('/opt')
sys.path.append('/opt/payupjack')
sys.path.append('/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env')
sys.path.append('/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack') 

# Reorder sys.path so new directories at the front.

new_sys_path = []

for item in list(sys.path):

    if item not in prev_sys_path:

        new_sys_path.append(item)

        sys.path.remove(item)

sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path

activate_this = '/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/bin/activate_this.py'

execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from os.path import abspath, dirname, join


print  sys.path

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "PayupJack.settings"

sys.path.insert(0, join("/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack", "apps"))


import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()


print 'Last step of WSGI'

application = WSGIHandler()

print 'Done final step. '
```

And here is my Apache config file:

```
WSGIPythonPath /opt/payupjack/payupjack_env/lib/python2.7

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        WSGIDaemonProcess payupjack python-path=/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env:/opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages processes=1 threads=1

        WSGIProcessGroup payupjack

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

        WSGIPassAuthorization On



        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack/wsgi.py

        Alias /static/ /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack/static

        <Directory /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/PayupJack>

                Order deny,allow

                #Allow from all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/logs/error.log

        CustomLog /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**New Info**

The `ldd` of `mod_wsgi.so` returns:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff815f2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff5b3fec000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ff5b3a88000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff5b36c2000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff5b443c000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff5b34a9000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff5b32a5000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff5b30a1000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff5b2d9b000)
```

I also did a quick find on my whole hard drive and only found one python library that matches the above which is located at:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

Comment: The `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` error makes me thing it's an error related to 32- and 64-bit architectures. Do you have a 64-bit version of `psycopg2` ?

Comment: Yup. When I use the Python shell. I can import it with no issue at all.

Comment: Whether command line works doesn't matter as mod_wsgi links the Python library directly and doesn't use command line Python. Thus it could be linking an entirely different Python library/installation. See https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library and https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

Comment: To build on GrahamDumpleton's answer, what does the output of running this command: ldd mod_wsgi.so look like?

Comment: In both Python shell and mod_wsgi, I get sys.ver = '2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) [GCC 4.8.2]'    and    sys.prefix = '/usr'.

The ldd returns:

        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007ff5b3a88000))

Comment: But what does 'ldd mod_wsgi.so' give as that is the important one as it shows which specific Python run time library is being used? You can't rely on just 'sys.prefix' value.

Comment: Sorry Graham, I missed press Enter and so the comment posted earlier than I wanted it to. I have added new information on the ldd and the location of the python library in my post.

Comment: What do you get if run run ``file /opt/payupjack/payupjack-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so``.

Comment: Hi Graham, it showed 32-bits and from there onwards I was able to figure out the problem. I will be posting my solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to a path issue (thanks to Graham pointing out how to check the bitness and location of `psycopg2.so`). My application uses VirtualEnv. For some reasons, I did not set up VirtualEnv properly the first time. Therefore, all the package that was installed through `pip` stayed in the OS's python path and not VirtualEnv.

The solution was to remove all the packages installed on the OS's Python path. Then, recreate a new VirtualEnv and do the typical `pip install`. Make sure that all the packages are installed in the VirtualEnv path. Once I did that, everything worked beautifully.